# Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: 'Unable to parse composition' using Lottie in splashscreen xamarin forms (android)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, lottie

I'm getting an error Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: 'Unable to parse composition' when I try to use it on the splash screen

I'm using lottie vs 4.1

the code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:id="@+id/animation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:lottie_loop="false"
        app:lottie_speed="2.0"
        app:lottie_fileName="xamarin.json"
        app:lottie_autoPlay="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Is there a specific "build action" to set to the "xamarin.json" file? the default I have is set to "none"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xamarin.json` file will need to live in your `resource/raw` folder and have the build action set to `AndroidResource` (this should normally automatically happen when you add files to resources). If you set it to `none` it won't even be included in your project.

Comment: After changing "none" to "AndroidResource" I'm getting this error message ``invalid file path 'C:\MyAPP\MyAPP.Android\obj\Debug\130\res\assets\xamarin.json'``.

Comment: You put it in assets, and not in Resources/raw

Comment: I don't have this folder, should I create it?

Comment: Yes, create the `raw` folder so it is next to the `layout` folder where you have your layout for your splash screen

Comment: I also changed ``app:lottie_fileName="xamarin.json"`` to ``app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/xamarin"``